# how can I insert data by declaring all fields (not *)?

Tags: postgresql, insert

Here's my insert query:

```
    INSERT INTO listing_replica_child (
     (
      SELECT rtz_comma_list(column_name)
      FROM information_schema.columns
      WHERE table_name = 'listing'
     )
    )
VALUES (
    (
        SELECT (
               (
                SELECT rtz_comma_list(column_name)
                FROM information_schema.columns
                WHERE table_name = 'listing'
               ) 
                FROM listing
                WHERE listing_id = 9656
               )
        )
    );
```

I'm using postgres.

Comment: Why do you need something like that? The only way to do it, is to use dynamic SQL inside a PL/pgSQL function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
do $$
DECLARE rec TEXT;
BEGIN
    SELECT 'insert into listing_replica_child (' || t.col || ') select * from listing WHERE listing_id = 9656 '
    INTO rec
    FROM (
        SELECT string_agg(column_name, ',') col
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_name = 'listing'
        ) t;

    EXECUTE rec;
END;$$;
```

---

You can wrap this *dynamic query* into a function like this

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION insert_listing_replica_child (_listing_id INT)
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE rec TEXT;
BEGIN
    SELECT 'insert into listing_replica_child (' || t.col || ') select * from listing WHERE listing_id = ' || _listing_id || ' '
    INTO rec
    FROM (
        SELECT string_agg(column_name, ',') col
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_name = 'listing'
        ) t;

    EXECUTE rec;
END $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

So if want to insert values from `listing` table with `lissting_id=9656` into table `listing_replica_child`

just Call

```
select insert_listing_replica_child (9656)
```

Comment: listing_replica_child has all the columns of listing plus 3 another columns that's why I need to declare all listing's columns.

Comment: @Clem just update your question with more info and provide DDL of both tables

Comment: @Clem One more clarification what will be the values for `3 another columns` is it update as null when you insert values from `listing` table?

Comment: Yes, those three columns will be null. But I will update them after insert.

Comment: @Clem You can do something like [this](http://pastie.org/10083980) (_just define columns to insert in the insert statement_)

Comment: Yes. But is there a way to declare fields dynamically? I mean, i will not declare columns one by one.

Answer (score 0):

The way to specify all destination fields is to omit the column list entirely.

Your attempt then becomes:

```
INSERT INTO listing_replica_child
SELECT * FROM listing
WHERE listing_id = 9656
```

without loss of intention: If the number and type of the fields of the tables differs with your attempt, execution will explode (as will this query).

Even though you have asked that `*` not be used, it is the simplest and best way to achieve the task.

Comment: My first answer was this,gradually I've edited it according to OP's Comment

Comment: I see. If the answer rolls back to this query, let me know and I'll delete this one